# Unable to launch Visual studio 2012: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

So I've been having some computer problems recently and had to do a reset in windows 8 - this uninstalls all programs but leaves your files more or less intact. I've been going through and reinstalling everything, and I've found that I can no longer launch visual studio 2012.

I've done a complete reinstall and i've also removed the windows 8 phone SDK which may have been interfering.

When I try to launch VS2012 I get the error message: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= or one of it's dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like .NET Framework 4.0 is missing - VS2012 will only have installed 4.5 I think.

Comment: @RogerRowland- my 2012 Ultimate has .NET all the way back to 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

1. Download this [cleanup tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx) to uninstall .net framework currently in your system.
2. Read about clean up tool [here](http://techdows.com/2012/08/remove-net-framework-4-5-with-net-framework-cleanup-tool.html).
3. Download the latest .net framework in [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653).
4. Install the framework and reboot.

Comment: One of the problems i'm running into is that because this is windows 8 I don't think that I can actually reinstall the framework. The installer says "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5 redistributable." Same thing with 4.0.

Comment: go to cntrol panel>programs>programs & features and then go to Turn Windows features on or off, make sure that .NET Framework 3.5 and .NET Framework 4.5 is checked. 3.5 is optional.

Comment: So, both .net 3.5 and .net 4.5 are installed and checked. I cannot use that cleanup tool as all of the relevant versions of .net are installed as OS components. I ran the .net verification tool posted [here](http://techdows.com/2012/07/net-framework-verification-tool-adds-net-3-5-and-windows-8-support.html) and it says they are both installed correctly and functioning. I'm getting a new motherboard tomorrow so I guess i'll just do another OS reset then. It's worth noting that VS2012 wont even let me uninstall itself now, it hangs on "creating system restore point"

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem on win 8 , vs 2012 . The utilities indicate frameworks are correctly installed. Cannot remove and reinstall frameworks from win 8 , have tried reinstalling and repairing studio. Cant see any way out apart from reinstalling the OS. And btw have tried system restore.

Answer (score 0):

Well after losing a day in trying out various options. I took a closer look at the windows updates and uninstalled the ones loaded the day before this problem started. And we are back in action. So if you are in the same boat as me, try uninstalling the updates before trying other stuff.